# addImportToModule returns empty array of changes

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I'm trying to use angular schematics to add imports to NgModule. I'm using `Angular 16.2.5`. Here's the code of the logic:

```
import { addImportToModule, insertImport} from '@schematics/angular/utility/ast-utils';
import * as ts from 'typescript';

function addImport(
  importPath: string,
  importName: string,
  tree: Tree,
  context: SchematicContext
): Tree {
  const modulePath = '/src/app/app.module.ts';

  if (!tree.exists(modulePath)) {
    throw new SchematicsException(`The file ${modulePath} doesn't exist!`);
  }

  const appModuleFile = tree.read(normalize(modulePath))?.toString('utf-8');
  
  if (appModuleFile === null) {
    throw new SchematicsException(`Cannot read the ${modulePath}module!`);
  }

  var source = ts.createSourceFile(
    modulePath,
    appModuleFile!,
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
    true
  );

  const importChange = insertImport(source, modulePath, importName, importPath, true)
  const importsChanges = addImportToModule(source, modulePath,importName,importPath);

  const changes = [importChange, ...importsChanges]
  const importRecorder = tree.beginUpdate(modulePath);

  for (const change of changes) {
    context.logger.debug(change.description);
    if (change instanceof InsertChange) {
      context.logger.info('Found change.');
      importRecorder.insertLeft(change.pos, change.toAdd);
    }
    else{
      context.logger.info('Something else');
    }
  }

  tree.commitUpdate(importRecorder);

  return tree;
}
```

For some reason, `insertImport` is working as expected, but the `addImportToModule` is not - it's neither inserting the module nor inserting the module into NgModule imports array. The function itself return the empty array.

Here's the `AppModule` I'm trying to update (located at `src/app/app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've been going over many example in the internet, but they all look similar and nothing works for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, finally - will post here, maybe someone finds that useful.

I have two packages outdated (here are the corrected versions):

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.5"
"ng-packagr": "16.2.3"
```

Also, I changed the import from:
`import * as ts from 'typescript';` to `import * as ts from '@schematics/angular/third_party/github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/lib/typescript';` as it was required to build the project after the updates.

Comment: I had the same issue, and  upgrading @angular-devkit/build-angular didn't help (was already on 16.2.12). However, upgrading typescript to ~5.1.0 did help!
And I left the import as:
`import * as ts from 'typescript';`